# issue in vaadin with google cloud sql

Tags: java, google-app-engine, vaadin

I have made a Google App Engine project in Vaadin  with google cloud sql database. I've tested it well on my local machine, without (any important) bugs.

When I deploy it to GAE it also works for a certain time. Only after x hours it stops working (doing exactly the same as before and without changing anything to the code). If I deploy the project again, it is working again.

When I take a look at the GAE logs it seems to be a

```
2013-03-25 10:26:03.071 
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.GAEApplicationServlet service: An exception occurred while servicing request.
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.handleServiceException(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:1010)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:548)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.GAEApplicationServlet.service(GAEApplicationServlet.java:239)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
```